# Natural language processing - extracting data

Tags: python, nltk, data-extraction, information-extraction

I need help with processing unstructured data of day-trading/swing-trading/investment recommendations. I've the unstructured data in the form of `CSV`.

Following are 3 sample paragraphs from which data needs to be extracted:

> Chandan Taparia of Anand Rathi has a buy call on Coal India Ltd. with
>   an **intra-day** **target price of Rs 338** . The **current market
>   price of Coal India Ltd. is 325.15** . Chandan Taparia recommended to
>   keep **stop loss at Rs 318** .
>
> Kotak Securities Limited has a buy call on Engineers India Ltd. with a
>   **target price of Rs 335** .The **current market price of Engineers India Ltd. is Rs 266.05** The analyst gave **a year** for Engineers
>   India Ltd. price to reach the defined target. Engineers India enjoys a
>   healthy market share in the Hydrocarbon consultancy segment. It enjoys
>   a prolific relationship with few of the major oil & gas companies like
>   HPCL, BPCL, ONGC and IOC. The company is well poised to benefit from a
>   recovery in the infrastructure spending in the hydrocarbon sector.
>
> Independent analyst Kunal Bothra has a sell call on Ceat Ltd. with a
>   **target price of Rs 1150** .The **current market price of Ceat Ltd. is Rs 1199.6** The time period given by the analyst is **1-3 days**
>   when Ceat Ltd. price can reach the defined target. Kunal Bothra
>   maintained **stop loss at Rs 1240**.

Its been a challenge extracting 4 information out of the paragraphs:
each recommendation is differently framed but essentially has

1. Target Price
2. Stop Loss Price
3. Current Price.
4. Duration

and not necessarily all the information will be available in all the recommendations -  every recommendation will atleast have **Target Price**.

I was trying to use regular expressions, but not very successful, can anyone guide me how to extract this information may be using `nltk`?

Code I've so far in cleaning the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

#etanalysis_final.csv has 4 columns with 
#0th Column having data time
#1st Column having a simple hint like 'Sell  Ceat Ltd.  target Rs  1150  :   Kunal Bothra,Sell  Ceat Ltd.  at a price target of Rs  1150  and a stoploss at Rs  1240  from entry point', not all the hints are same, I can rely on it for recommender, Buy or Sell, which stock.
#4th column has the detailed recommendation given.

df = pd.read_csv('etanalysis_final.csv',encoding='ISO-8859-1')
df.DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df['RECBY'] = df['C1'].apply(lambda x: re.split(':|\x96',x)[-1].strip())
df['ACT'] = df['C1'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0].strip())
df['STK'] = df['C1'].apply(lambda x: re.split('\.|\,|:| target| has| and|Buy|Sell| with',x)[1])
#Getting the target price - not always correct
df['TGT'] = df['C4'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d+.', x)[0])
#Getting the stop loss price - not always correct
df['STL'] = df['C4'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d+.\d+', x)[-1])
```

Comment: You are doing a lot of regexes for a simple `find("target price of Rs (\d+)")`

Comment: Not all the time the target price is available as `target price of Rs` sometimes as `target 500` sometimes like `have 500 as target` etc..

Comment: Okay, but not in the data you provided... Anyways, natural language processing is quite difficult to get right. And it doesn't seem you've really tried to use it yet.

Comment: Certainly I've never used natural language processing. Did try something ipython - not worth saying anything about it.

Comment: ipython isn't related to `nltk`. Your post is at a risk of being closed as too broad unless you [edit] to include some attempts at solving the problems yourself using it. That was my point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution :

Code here contains only solution part of the question asked. It shall be possible to greatly improve this solution using [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) library.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize      
periods = ['year',"year's", 'day','days',"day's", 'month', "month's", 'week',"week's", 'intra-day', 'intraday']
stop = ['target', 'current', 'stop', 'period', 'stoploss']

def extractinfo(row):
    if 'intra day' in row.lower():
        row = row.lower().replace('intra day', 'intra-day')
    tks = [ w for w in word_tokenize(row) if any([w.lower() in stop, isfloat(w)])]
    tgt = ''
    crt = ''
    stp = ''
    prd = ''
    if 'target' in tks:
        if len(tks[tks.index('target'):tks.index('target')+2]) == 2:
            tgt = tks[tks.index('target'):tks.index('target')+2][-1]
    if 'current' in tks:
        if len(tks[tks.index('current'):tks.index('current')+2]) == 2:
            crt = tks[tks.index('current'):tks.index('current')+2][-1]
    if 'stop' in tks:
        if len(tks[tks.index('stop'):tks.index('stop')+2]) == 2:
            stp = tks[tks.index('stop'):tks.index('stop')+2][-1]
    prdd = set(periods).intersection(tks)       
    if 'period' in tks:
        pdd = tks[tks.index('period'):tks.index('period')+3]
        prr = set(periods).intersection(pdd)
        if len(prr) > 0:
            if len(pdd) > 2:
                prd = ' '.join(pdd[-2::1])
            elif len(pdd) == 2:
                prd = pdd[-1]
    elif len(prdd) > 0:
        prd = list(prdd)[0]
    return (crt, tgt, stp, prd)
```

Solution is relatively self explanatory - otheriwse please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard question in that there are different possibilities in which each of the 4 pieces of information might be written. Here is a naive approach that might work, albeit would require verification. I'll do the example for the target but you can extend this to any:

```
CONTEXT = 6

def is_float(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def get_target_price(s):
    words = s.split()
    n = words.index('target')
    words_in_range = words[n-CONTEXT:n+CONTEXT]
    return float(list(filter(is_float, words_in_range))[0]) # returns any instance of a float
```

This is a simple approach to get you started but you can put extra checks to make this safer. Things to potentially improve:

1. Make sure that the the index before the one where the proposed float is found is Rs.
2. If no float is found in the context range, expand the context
3. Add user verification if there are ambiguities i.e. more than one instance of target or more than one float in the context range etc.